# How to create a generic wrapper function that preserves signature and has a similar return type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm struggling to create a generic function that augments argument functions in a specific way

For example, is it possible to create a generic factory function that modifies a function in such a way that it may run or may not run?

```
const wrap = function <T extends Function>(func: T): T {
  const run = Math.random() % 2 > 0

  const wrapped = (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> | void => {
    if (run) {
      func(args)
    }
  }

  return wrapped
}
```

The code above shows the following errors:

```
Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.ts(2344)

Type '(...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> | void' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '(...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> | void' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Function'.ts(2322)
```

This version seems to work:

```
const wrap = function <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(func: T): T {
  const run = Math.random() % 2 > 0

  const wrapped = (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> | void => {
    if (run) {
      return func(...args)
    } else {
      console.log('skipped')
    }
  }

  return (wrapped as unknown) as T
}

const testFunc = (foo: string, bar: number) => {
  console.log('testing', foo, bar)
  return 'test_result'
}

const wrappedTestFunc = wrap(testFunc)

const res = wrappedTestFunc('aaa', 5)

console.log('returned result', res)
```

It seems to work, but it feels like a 'hack', because it uses `as unknown`. Does it have any caveats? Maybe there is a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**

Replace `Function` with `AnyFunction`.

Reason: you can't infer `Parameters` nor `ReturnType` of `Function`, because `Function` doesn't actually represent a function signature. It represents the global JavaScript `Function` object.

**Step 2**

Don't say that `wrap` returns `T`. It returns either

- whatever `T` returns, or
- does not return (returns `void`)

The correct signature for `wrap` is `<T extends AnyFunction>(func: T): (...parameters: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> | void`.

**Solution**

```
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

const wrap = function <T extends AnyFunction>(func: T): (...parameters: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> | void {
  const run = Math.random() % 2 > 0

  const wrapped = (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> | void => {
    if (run) {
      func(args)
    }
  }

  return wrapped
}
```